# Parse a series of strings into an array of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, forms, parsing

Being new to PHP and having looked at documentation and whatnot, I'm unable to find the answer to this question.

I want to take a `$_POST` input like:

```
Large Automated Structural Restoration  1   Hull Repair Unit        Medium  50 m3
Experimental 10MN Microwarpdrive I  5   Propulsion Module       Medium  50 m3
Warp Disruptor I    1   Warp Scrambler      Medium  5 m3
Upgraded EM Ward Amplifier I    1   Shield Amplifier        Medium  5 m3
Tracking Disruptor I    1   Tracking Disruptor  Small   Medium  5 m3
```

Into an `array` like:

```
[Experimental 10MN Microwarpdrive I] [5] [Propulsion Module] [] [Medium] [50] //Disregard m3
[Warp Disruptor I] [1] [Warp Scrambler] [] [Medium] [5]
...
[Tracking Disruptor I] [1] [Tracking Disruptor] [Small] [Medium] [5]
```

To where I could call a variable like `$asset[0][name]` so I can prepare an XML call out to an external resource.

The logic is escaping me or I'm not understanding something. Please help!

Comment: Is that POST value one big string?

Comment: Looks to me like tab separated data. Use `fgetcsv` or `strgetcsv` function to "parse" it.

Comment: Do you get the initial string really as a single string from a $_POST element?

Comment: Does the original data use tabs? It looks like spaces on here.

Comment: Looks like we're all waiting on how that data is sent so we know how to handle it properly. *tapping foot...*

Comment: just happy to see something being done with **warp technology**. congrats Kevin for working on this ;)

Comment: Also, sometimes the name will have numbers in the front (IE: 10MN Afterburner I)

Comment: Didn't expect a quick response. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$aero=explode(PHP_EOL,trim($_POST['textarea'])); //separate each line
$asset=array(); //init the assets
foreach ($aero as $unit) { //loop each line
    $detail=explode("\t",$unit); //split by tab
    $name=$detail[0]; //assign the name to the first item in the arr
    unset($detail[count($detail)-1]); //delete the last item ('m3' not needed)
    unset($detail[0]); //delete the first item (we saved it as $name)
    $asset[][$name]=$detail; //add an array item
}
```

Just for the fun, here's another solution using a regex 1-liner when you wouldn't have tabs:

```
$regex='/^([A-Za-z0-9 ]+) (\d+) ([A-Z][A-Za-z ]+?)(\ ()|\ (Small)\ )([A-Z][a-z]+) (\d+) m3$/m';
preg_match_all($regex,$textarea,$aero);
$asset=array();    
foreach ($aero[1] as $no=>$unit) {
    $asset[$unit]=array($aero[2][$no],
                $aero[3][$no], 
                $aero[6][$no], 
                $aero[7][$no], 
                $aero[8][$no]); 
}
```

Would probably need a small addition for this bit: `(\ ()|\ (Small)\ )` something along the lines of `(\ ()|\ (Small)\ |\ (Medium)\ |\ (Large)\ )`

Regex output for the first and last lines from example before processing:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Large Automated Structural Restoration 1 Hull Repair Unit Medium 50 m3 [1] => Tracking Disruptor I 1 Tracking Disruptor Small Medium 5 m3 )  
[1] => Array ( [0] => Large Automated Structural Restoration [1] => Tracking Disruptor I )  
[2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 )  
[3] => Array ( [0] => Hull Repair Unit [1] => Tracking Disruptor )  
[4] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Small )  
[5] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )  
[6] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Small )  
[7] => Array ( [0] => Medium [1] => Medium )  
[8] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 5 ) )
```

Comment: I was more interested in separating each line, then having
`1. Large Automated Structural Restoration (name), 1 (qty), ...
2. Experimental 10MN... `
to where I could call $asset[0]['name'] and it would return "Large Automated Strctural Restoration". :)

Comment: I gave you the answer however because you've provided me massive amounts of information for me to resolve it.

Comment: Great to be of help, you might want to use `$asset[1]['name']=$detail[0];$asset[1]['qty']=$detail[1]...` instead (you need a counter instead if **1**). just do a `<pre>print_r()` to seek what you need

Comment: Seems the way I did it worked fine.
`foreach ($aero as $unit) { //loop each line
 $detail=explode("\t",$unit); //split by tab

 $asset[]=array(
   "name"=>$detail[0],
   "qty"=>intval($detail[1]),
   "type"=>$detail[2],
   "slot"=>$detail[3],
   "size"=>$detail[4],
   "total_volume"=>$detail[5]
   );
}`

Answer (score 0):

if you `explode` the string with a delimiter of a regex of >1 whitespace, then everything would be in an array that you could do what you want with.

```
$reg = '\s+';
$ar = explode($reg,$_POST['val']);
```

Comment: ahh, so just need to tweak the regex, but the `explode` would get it right, no? And we don't know if they are tabs or spaces yet.

Comment: @KevinDethlefs-Moreno: they look like spaces after SO's editor finished with them but you pasted the text with tabs. are you sure you don't have tabs? and no, `\t` *(tab)* won't take into account for spaces

Comment: how does your html form look like? paste the snippet